# Which Manchester team's jersey did Jimmy's dad send him?

Tags: youre-the-worst

In the episode "Equally Dead Inside" of "You're the Worst" which of the Manchester teams' shirt did Jimmy's dad send him? The blue doesn't seem right for City but surely it's not a United shirt.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like it might be the Manchester United away jersey from 2011/2012 season.

I just got a quick glimpse of the jersey on the show, but from what I saw this jersey seems to be the best match.

http://www.football-shirts.co.uk/fans/manchester-united-nike-away-shirt-201112_12055

Comment: There's a better view towards the end. And a player name -starts with Hensers.. And from the front it looks like a Ch*lsea strip with the badge. I'm thinking it might be completely made up.

Comment: Well, the Manchester United away jerseys 2011/2012 look like the Chelsea home jerseys. (there was quite the controversy with fans) You are probably correct though, it is more than likely made up.

Answer (score 0):

If I may, it seems to be an Everton Jersey (Liverpool) so either the producers don't give a damn about soccer or they completely messed up.